# Blank space under first row in table

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am using the package `booktabs` to create a simple table in my document.

Here is the code I use to generate my table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Tabelle}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        A & B & C \\
        \midrule
        D & E & F \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

In the **the first** table that I create in my document with this code, the first row is twice as long as normal. If I generate a second table with the same code, it look correct (see picture below).

[image]

I cannot explain this behavior. Why does this only occur in the fist table and not after and how can I fix my table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please always post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Please make your code ready for copy&run.

Comment: with your code fragment, inserte3d in article document with default settings can not reproduce your first image. Result is quite4 close to the your second image. So please again (as others) , provide complete small document which reproduce your problem. For sure its source is not in your code fragment.